# Raku: Mutually recursive tokens cause a "method not found" error

Tags: regex, raku

I've simplified a more complicated pattern I'm trying to match down to the following program:

```
my token paren { '(' <tok> ')' }
my token tok { <paren>? foo }

say "(foo)foo" ~~ /<tok>/;
```

This seems straightforward enough to me, but I get this error:

```
No such method 'tok' for invocant of type 'Match'.  Did you mean 'to'?
  in regex paren at a.p6 line 1
  in regex tok at a.p6 line 2
  in block <unit> at a.p6 line 4
```

What's the reason for this error?

The pattern matches without error if I change the first `<tok>` to `<&tok>`, but then I don't get a capture of that named pattern, which, in my original, more-complicated case, I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `tok` isn't in the current lexical namespace yet, so `<tok>` gets compiled as a method call instead.

If you force it to be a lexical call with `&`, it works.

```raku
my token paren { '(' <&tok> ')' }
my token tok { <paren>? foo }

say "(foo)foo" ~~ /<tok>/;
```

If `<…>` starts with anything other than a letter it doesn't capture.

So to capture it under the name `tok`, we add `tok=` to the `<…>`

```raku
my token paren { '(' <tok=&tok> ')' }
my token tok { <paren>? foo }

say "(foo)foo" ~~ /<tok>/;
```

Answer (score 9):

Brad's answer is correct, but I wanted to offer another possible solution: you can recurse within a single regex using the special [`<~~>` token](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Recursive_Regexes).  Using that, plus a regular named capture, would create the captures you want in the simplified example in your question; here's how that would look:

```
my token paren { $<tok> = ['(' <~~> ')']? foo }
```

I'm not sure whether your more complicated case can be as easily re-written to recurse on itself rather than with two mutually recursive tokens.  But, when this pattern works, it can simplify the code quite a bit.